# Query with three propertys using JPA Respository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following model for `LineItem` and i want to create a query that gives me all LineItems with this three given filters: `Order.ordered (date)`, `LineItem.price (BigDecimal)` and `Product.idProduct (Long)`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lines_item", catalog = "orders_app")
public class LineItem implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idlinesItem;
    private Product product;
    private Order order;
    private Integer quantity;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public LineItem() {
    }
```

Iam using JPA Respository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
public interface LineItemRepository extends JpaRepository<LineItem, Long>{     
List <LineItem> findByOrderOrdered(Date ordered);//<--somethiglikethis
}
```

Comment: Personally I would use a `@Query` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query method would look something like:

```
List <LineItem> findByOrder_OrderedAndPriceAndProduct_IdProduct(Date ordered, BigDecimal price, Long productId);
```

Refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) for more details on query method.

For such complex queries instead of making longer method names, as @scary-wombat suggested you can use JPA queries with `@Query` like below.

```
Query("select item from LineItem item where order.ordered = :ordered and item.price = :price and product.idProduct = : productId")
List <LineItem> findByOrderAndPriceAndProduct(Date ordered, BigDecimal price, Long productId)
```

Please note above queries are not tested though you get the idea to work on.